# Big problems with AD gpo

Tags: windows-server-2003, group-policy

I have a problem with a gpo on AD.
Well, I have a domain root where I have only one domain policy. In the policy there is a permission on "log on as service" and two 2 groups added.
Down the root I have 1 OU and some other leaf OU as user,groups,computers and servers.
Under servers I have al my servers. Then the servers have just one gpo that is the domain policy.
The servers have applied the domain gpo as it should be. But there is one that have only one group under the "log on as service" policy.
If I run gpo result it show me that the server should have just one group and it look that it apply the policy correctly. But for my logic it should have two groups... what's happening ?

Comment: Where does the resultant set of policy show that setting as coming from?

Comment: Do you have any SCECLI errors in your event log?  Perhaps with an error 0x534?  See: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324383

Comment: ok, it should be resolved. I dont know why the kaspersky antivirus would have blocked the gpo apply.

Answer (score 0):

Kaspersky blocks gpo application. Do not know why.